# How to find all member classes in owner class?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

We have this class defined in C#:

```
class Course
{
  Teacher teacher;
  string courseName;
  int courseId;
}
```

How can we search all Teacher objects in Course(s)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about. Please write some use case

Comment: There will be only one Teacher object

Comment: You can't - they are private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one insteace of teacher in Course class. You can search course collection to find unique teacher records using [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx).

```
var result = courses.Distinct(c=>c.CourseId).Select(c=>c.Teacher);
```

Note You will need to make `Teacher` *public* property and also `CourseId` should be `public` as well.

Comment: It will work only if `teacher` is public, but it isn't

Comment: @wudzik CourseId too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List<Course>`, then you might do something like this:

```
var teachers = courses.Where(c => c.Teacher.Property == "value");
```